# How can I reach other pages of website when admin logs in

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router

How can I reach other pages when admin logs in. Always show dashboard page when I click others link. Can you please check my code.

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
  if (!Meteor.user()) {
    this.render('login');
  }  else {
    this.render('dashboard');
  }
});


Router.route('users', function() {
    this.render('users');
});
Router.route('orders', function() {
    this.render('orders');
});
```

Note: When I click users and order's link it shows me to dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That because it is intercepted by the `onBeforeAction`you should do something like this:

EDIT: Using https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles you need:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
  if (!Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), ['admin'])) {
    if (!Meteor.user()) {
      this.render('login');
    }  else {
      this.render('dashboard');
    }
  }
});
```

So if the user is an admin it pass the `onBeforeAction` and gets the next valid route

Comment: ı addedt this code but I get this error  Meteor.admin is not a function

Comment: That's only a sample, I don't know how you can check if a user is admin or not, but that isn't the question.

Comment: Answer updated if you are using this to manage roles https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles but you should update your question because it's unclear you need to find who is admin.

Comment: actually I didnt know this packets meteor add alanning:roles,ı think problem is about this,bcs I dont use it

Comment: I have an question to you,I have to use allaning:roles packet?I mean for example if I add a field to users collection as authority and I give "admin" to this document,and for others users give "normaluser" can't I solve this?